# While editing e.g. code, documents via Remote Desktop, select gets stuck (Windows 7, Server 2008, Server 2012)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I frequently edit documents and code over remote desktop. I've noticed frequently select gets 'stuck', particularly when I use ctrl+ for jumping words while selecting text. Occasionally using crtl+arrow to de-select the text will get me out of it but typically the session becomes unusable after this. Have to then close and re-open the RDP session. It's not an issue with sticky keys/accessibility settings. Surprisingly I can't find anything on the web about this but I encounter it very frequently and suspect it's a bug.

Has anyone else encountered this? Can anyone point to a resolution or bug report?

Comment: What are the OSes from where and to where you are connecting? For me double-tapping the stuck key will "unstick" it.

Comment: OS from: Win7. OS to: Win 7/Win 2008/Win 2012. There's no stuck key, it's like an invisible spot in the editor and if you mouse click anywhere else it selects text from invisible spot to that point. No way to not select something. Ctrl x or ctrl c do not cut of copy as expected. Also networking may be a contributory factor. Doesn't seem to occur when on the same LAN, only via VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be resolved when using the Windows 10 RDP client.

It could be mitigated sometimes in Windows 7 client by pressing ctrl+shift / ctrl+alt (sometimes with arrow keys to select/de-select, which usually triggers the issue).

Seemed to be a combination of VPN + RDP on Win 7 triggering the issue as it never happened on LAN.